# Using python and numpy to compute gradient of the regularized loss function

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have the following formula:

[image: RLF]

That I'm trying to use in a function to compute the gradient of the regularized loss function. I have the `dataSet`, which is an array of `[(x(1), t(1)), ..., (x(n), t(n))]`, and with the training data `n = 15`.

Here's what I have so far, knowing that the loss function is the [vector here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htteR.png)

```
def gradDescent(alpha, t, w, Z):
    returned = 2 * alpha * w
    y = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(dataSet):
        y.append(dataSet[i][0] * w[i])
        i+= 1
    return(returned - (2 * np.sum(np.subtract(t, y)) * Z))
```

---

The issue is, `w` is always equal to `(M + 1`) - whereas in the `dataSet`, `t` is equal to `15`. This results in an out of bound multiplication. Am I calculating the formula wrong? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are messing up your indexing on the data set array. Also make sure your array is actually defined as an array and not a list. I believe lists index like list[i][j] and arrays index like array[i,j].

So I would run your data object through:

```
import numpy as np
dataSet=np.asarray(dataSet)
```

Then replace your while loop with this while loop:

```
while i < len(dataSet):
        y.append(dataSet[i,0] * w[i])
        i+= 1
```

Comment: The issue with that is that `w` then becomes out of bounds, as `w` is anywhere from 1-15, while dataTrain is always 15.

Comment: To be clear W is a vector of dimension (15,1) and dataSet is a vector of dimension (15,2)?

Comment: And I'm not sure what you are referencing by dataTrain, that is not a defined variable in the code you provided.

Comment: also are you defining your function y(x) as y(x(i))=x(i)*w(i)?

Comment: Sorry, `dataSet` is what I meant. And `W` is a vector of dimensions `(M, 1)` and `dataSet` is a vector of dimensions `(15, 2)`. `M` can be anywhere from `1-16` depending on how the graph is fit.

And I'm unsure, I think that's how y(x) is calculated but I can't find any information on that. For now, I'm going with that until my professor replies confirming it.

Comment: Can you provide me with the paper or other documentation where you got this equation from? It is not clear to me what W is. It seems to me that the length of W should strictly be the length of your dataSet

Comment: Question 5(c) from here: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bonner/courses/2017f/csc411/assignments/hw1.pdf
I'm also confused, the professor isn't replying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156231/discussion-between-ian-campbell-moore-and-andrew-raleigh).